How to make LEDs dimmable
I purchased 5 meters of these dual white light led strips the 120 LEDs per meter at 12 V.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005007652415671.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.10.5af11802vq8ghP
Wattage: Max. 120 LEDs/m --> 8 W/m.
My original plan was to use an ESP3266 chip (D1 mini) and turn the LEDs on/off with a relay, but now considering going a bit more fancy and see if I could make them dimmable.
The ESP32 does have PWM on some pins, but only at 3.3 V output.  The led strip needs 12 V.  What could I use to send the PWM to the LEDs power source?  Would a MOSFET work in this case?

So after doing some more reading seems I could use a mosfet with a V_GS_th under 3v.  The issue I now have is that I don't have access to mosfets locally (cancun Mx), but I do have access to transistors.  Could a transistor work as well?

Depends on what are your specs for dimming and your circuit if it can match your specs. We don't know. Of course a transistor could be used. You intend to switch the whole 12V 3.33A strip?

I only plan to use 3 meters, so at 8W/m it would be 24W, at 12V would be 2A.  The listing of strips I purchased is not detailed, I am assuming it would be 8W/m with both the cool white and warm white turned on.  It does have 3 wires, but at this point not even sure if 1 wire if for gnd, and the other 2 are V+ for each color, or if 1 wire is for V+ and the other two GND for each color.  I do know I would need two mosfets or transistors, each would handle about 1A if I am  understanding correctly

Link says LEDs are dimmable.  Try decreasing voltage and see what impact it has on LEDs.

Thanks @StainlessSteelRat   I actually just noticed that the listing does state they are dimmable, but assuming I could dim the lights with lover voltage, how could I control the voltage with an ESP8266?

Your ESP8266 drives a variable voltage power supply.  Or PWM via FETs on 12V power.  The problem with aliexpress, you don't know until you try something.

So going through my junk drawer I found some NDP6020P's, that is a mosfet correct?  However it is a P Channel, would it still work?

@StainlessSteelRat Ok, I don't have a variable voltage power supply, so seems PWM via FETs is the way I will go.  Seem N Channel MOSFET is what I would ideally use, but only have access to some P Channel MOSFETs, could those work as well?

@CancunManny You need to know first if the LEDs have common anode or common cathode, to know if you need to PWM the 12V side or the 0V side, which defines if you should use P or N FETs.

@StainlessSteelRat I took a closer look at the pictures of the strips.  It lists 12v then w and r, so that means the share the same anode (12v) side.  That means I need an N FET correct?

I'd look up 2835 CCT.

@CancunManny A MOSFET is a type of transistor.

@StainlessSteelRat I'm running a similar 24V strip off a 19V laptop supply to hit the right light level.  The structure is a series chain with a resistor, a cut mark, another series chain etc.  Crude, but effective.  Mine is in work where AliExpress isn't allowed so we have to pay nearly 10× as much; PWM also wouldn't be desirable in our optics labs

Assuming the seller's data is correct, 5m @ 8W/m is 40W, or 3.3A at 12VDC. So maybe you only need 2A for a part of that, from the comments.
Unfortunately, most through-hole MOSFETs (and most high current MOSFETs in general) require more than 3.3V to fully turn on. While it's possible a tiny SOT-23 MOSFET could work if you were careful, it might be better to grab some parts that are more common and robust such as a TO-220 MOSFET.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
M1 can be a better and more modern MOSFET than the IRF530, but most low voltage MOSFETs (Vds rating) in a TO-220 or TO-251 package that are characterized at 10V Vgs will be adequate. The BJTs can be just about any jellybean silicon transistor like 2N3904, S8050, C1815 etc. and teh equivalent PNP types.
Note: R4 represents the maximum load of about 3.3A that the strip would. Here is a simulation with a PWM frequency of 1kHz:

One advantage of this driver circuit is that it lessens the chances that a mishap will damage the ESP32 fatally, since R3 prevents much current from flowing even if something gets shorted to +12V.
If you don't care about 'low' being 'on'  you can drop the first NPN transistor Q1 and R1, which is just an inverter, and drive the base of Q2 directly through R3.

Thanks for the great feedback.  I am still learning how to read diagrams, but the LED strip I've purchased is basically two strips in one.  I only plan to use about 3 meters of the strip, so that brings me down to 24 watts, 2A.  But since it is two strips in one, each strip would only pull about 1A.
What I don't understand at all is the R4.  Obviously I know almost nothing about electronics, but I was under the impression that LEDs are a type of resistor so why would I need to add an actual resistor at the end?

@CancunManny That's just a resistor that represents the load of the strips, it's not a resistor you would install. I'll edit to explain that.

Ok, thanks for the quick response.  Somewhat proud of myself since it seems I was thinking in the right direction as far as LEDs being somewhat like a resistor.    Since I plan to light up 2 strips, would basically do the same thing twice right?

Yes, if you need to dim them individually. Otherwise you can just parallel the strips and use one PWM.
